# Calling function on onclick event in jsp with out as parameter

Tags: function, jsp, call

In this code I try to call jsp function on onclick event but it not working

```
<%@page language="java" %>
<html>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="radio" value="a" name="r">add</input>
            <input type="radio" value="s" name="r">update</input>
            <input type="radio" value="d" name="r">delete</input>
            <input type="radio" value="f" name="r">clear</input>
            <input type="button" onclick="<%a(out);%>">
        </form>
        <%!
            public void a(JspWriter myOut){
                try{
                    myOut.println("<h1>df");
                }
                catch(Exception eek){}
            }
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please inline the source code directly in your question. Also be more specific on what you expect and what is not working. How do you know it isn't working? What have you tried?

Comment: please add your full code

Comment: I edited your question to format the code as code, not as a photo of your code. Please format your code as code in the future. Also, you might find screenshots useful. To make a screenshot in Windows, you can press the Print Screen key and then paste in Paint. However, don't post screenshots of your code, post the code formatted like I formatted it, by indenting each line by 4 spaces.

Comment: So sorry, & thanks. Next time this mistake not get repeat.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a classic one: The key is to realize, **where** and **when** which code is executed - JSP on the server when the page is requested and rendered (i.e. **before** the response is send to the browser) and Javascript in the browser, **after** the browser receives the already generated response.

I.e. all your code between `<%` and `%>` is executed on the server, thus the resulting html code for the button is `<input type="button" onclick="" >`. To call JSP/servlet (or any server-side) code from Javascript, look for AJAX.